# Dropdown component not having effect in Chromium browser

Tags: angular, chart.js, chromium, eventemitter, angular-event-emitter

I have a simple pie chart with a dropdown component (based on `<select>`) which is used to toggle chart's data (I'm using angular 6). It works in firefox, but when I test it out on chromium nothing happens (as if the user did not select anything on the dropdown menu at all). Why does this happen? Full working example is on the stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/github/petarGitNik/chromium-chart-js-bug).

For example, in the [SelectComponent](https://stackblitz.com/github/petarGitNik/chromium-chart-js-bug?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect%2Fselect.component.ts) there is the `onClick` method that emits the selected values (value from the `<option>` element):

```
onClick(value: string): void {
  console.log(`I'm emitting ${value}`);
  this.select.emit(value);
}
```

and in the template:

```
<select>
  <option
    *ngFor="let item of items"
    value="{{item.value}}"
    (click)="onClick(item.value)"
  >{{ item.label }}</option>
</select>
```

I've added `console.log` for debugging, and it's normally printed out to console on the firefox, but on the Chromium it's not printed to the console at all, as if the `onClick` method was never called.

I've also tried `onClick($event)` instead of `onClick(item.value)`, but nothing happened.

Did anyone encountered similar problem, is this some chartjs bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: move your click event to select, and everything will work smooth

Comment: @AliAdravi if I change `(click)` to `(select)` it stops working in firefox too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using (change) event on select element instead of (click) on option

```
<select (change)="onChange($event)">
  ...
```

You can access the current value from

```
$event.target.value
```

The reason behind using the change event instead of a click event on option is that chrome does not trigger such a event on select options - so it's not related to angular.

Comment: I've made a change you suggested, and it seems to work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/working-version However, I'm not sure exactly why? Also, should I changed the `@Output() select` to some other name to avoid clashing with default browsers implementation of `(select)`?

Comment: As i've mentioned in my answer , chrome does not trigger 'click' event on option elements. Some browser's do, some don't so it's not the way to handle this kind of problems if you're aiming for cross-browser support.  You can read about this here http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-280-lack-of-events-for-options.html . Its old entry but still seem's to be the issue